# Where is the error in this SQL syntax?

Tags: php, sql

Ignoring the fact that concatenating user input into SQL strings is possibly the worst thing you can do in terms of avoiding SQL injection (this is not for a production site), what is wrong with the following SQL?

```
"SELECT '_id', 'email', 'password', 'salt', 'banned', 'ban_reason' FROM 'tbl_users' WHERE 'email'='" . $email . "' LIMIT 1";
```

I'm getting the error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'_id\', \'email\', \'password\', \'salt\', \'banned\', \'ban_reason\' FROM \'tb' at line 1

I'm using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on it right before running the query, hence the backslashes.

I also tried enclosing everything in backticks, but the error changed then to unknown column.

Comment: Remove all single quotes

Comment: To escape field names in MySQL use the backtick, not the single quote.

Comment: Don't insert variables in to SQL by concatenating strings, use prepared statements with placeholders.

Comment: Your other major problem seems to be the application of `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on the *whole* SQL query. That's not what it is or.

Comment: (Don't worry too much about downvotes - they happen. However it's not ideal to put commentary about votes in questions - questions are intended for a wide future audience, and they don't want to read about voting!).

Comment: @Mario's right - run your parameters through `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, not the whole query.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly where it says. "near '\'_id\'"

You use `` `backticks` `` to surround column and table names. Not `'single quotes'`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be escaping your variables you're inserting, not your query, and using backticks around field names

```
$sql = "SELECT `_id`, `email`, `password`, `salt`, `banned`, `ban_reason` FROM `tbl_users` WHERE `email`='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($email) . "' LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT `_id`, `email`, `password`, `salt`, `banned`, `ban_reason` FROM tbl_users WHERE `email`='" . $email . "' LIMIT 1"
```

You should use ` instead of ' when selecting fields.

Comment: Tried this, but now the error says "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'user@example.com\' LIMIT 1' at line 1"

Comment: Did you also put the backticks in the **WHERE 'email' = ...** ?

Comment: As your example I put them around the column name, but not the criteria. I've tried plenty of combinations but the same error message :/

Comment: @Adam Notice the backslashes. Are you `mysql_real_escape_string`ing your entire query???